# One-Page Website Menu in jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm interested in a jQuery menu like this in order to keep all the informations of my website on a single page. (Example: http://www.imagesup.net/?di=614084454059) I don't know how to define a menu like this, can you please help me?

Comment: This question is too broad. Check out some guides and come back with a more specific issue in combination with some code you've tried out!

Comment: Try this list: http://www.designrazzi.net/css-tab-menus.html they will also give you the code which you can read and understand

Comment: I just want to know what kind of menu is this because I basically don't know how to identify it! How can I check out some guides if I don't know what I'm looking for?

Comment: jquery UI also have something similar to this

Comment: See [**this**](http://bit.ly/1td1rKi)

Answer (score 0):

A simplest example how it can be done (although there are various other ways):

## [JSFIDDLE LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wmfux4bh/)

## HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li data-toggle-class="home">Home</li>
            <li data-toggle-class="about">About</li>
            <li data-toggle-class="contact">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="home">
        <p>This is a home section</p>
    </section>
    <section class="about">
        <p>This is an about section</p>
    </section>
    <section class="contact">
        <p>This is a contact section</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

## jQuery

```
$(".wrapper li").click(function(){
    var classToToggle = $(this).data("toggle-class");
    $(".wrapper section").css("display", "none");
    $("." + classToToggle).css("display", "block");
});
```

EDIT:

A little bit [styled version](http://jsfiddle.net/wmfux4bh/3/embedded/result/) of JSFIDDLE